# Arc.js not drawing line in OpenLayers 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

my code is

```
    const testSource = new VectorSource({
      loader: () => {
        const start2 = { x: 43.449928, y: 39.956589 };
        const end2 = { x: 55.606186, y: 49.278728 };

        const generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start2, end2);


        const line = generator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
        const features = [];
        line.geometries.forEach((geometry) => {
          const line = new LineString(geometry.coords);
          line.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
          const style = new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: '#EAE911',
              width: 2,
            }),
          });

          features.push(new Feature({ geometry: line }));

          features.forEach((feature) => {
            feature.setStyle(style);
            testSource.addFeature(feature);
          });
        });
      },
    });

    const vectorLineLayer = new VectorLayer({
      className: 'drawing-layer',
      source: testSource,
    });
    mapReference.addLayer(vectorLineLayer);
```

I can see that the source exists inside my layer but it will not draw no matter what I do, any ideas? It's not a zIndex issue because I have my vectorLayer CSS set zIndex.

**EDIT 5/2/2022**
turns out this line was giving me issues,

```
line.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

it was somehow turning my flat coordinates into insane lat/lon. deleting it now shows my curved lines

Comment: It works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/flight-animation-forked-vls2zh?file=/main.js

Comment: `line.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');` would not be needed if the view projection is EPSG:4326. To handle any view projection is should be `line.transform('EPSG:4326', mapReference.getView().getProjection());`

Comment: @Mike what's the point of doing this transform in the first place? is it needed?

Comment: If the view projection is not EPSG:4326 is is needed.  Most maps do not use EPSG:4326 for the view.